# How multi layer PCB are connected

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I've been watching videos how to make PCB at home and I understand the process. But none of them shows how 2 sides are connected, I see on some PCBs there are some circular end points, so it must be going to other side. But how is it connected ?

On arduino mini, I can see the coating inside header holes ? So does it require to coat carbon again ?

Answer (score 3):

When PCBs are produced in a factory the holes are plated through using a chemical process, but when making PCBs at home you have to put a wire or component lead through and solder both sides.

Comment: some attempts have been made at DIY plate through, but you need industrial chemicals like methanoi and calcium hypophosphite

Comment: They also sell rivets in various sizes that you can insert and crimp down.

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy: Exactly what I thought when reading the question, and imho this would be the better answer. And btw. there are some producty like LPKF ProConduct that don't need any "bad" checmicals.